# How do you store webform submits to a different database?

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a client requirement where "user generated content", in specific, webform submissions from the public, need to be stored in a different database from the normal 'one' database approach.

How do I configure the site to store webform submissions in a different database?

Comment: which drupal version you use ?

Comment: Good question...    D8

Answer (score 1):

General the most secure way is to push a webform submission into a different 'external' database is to create a webservice to populate the external database. Then you can use the 'Remote post' handler to push the submission data via the webservice into the external database.

@see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-videos#handlers

To disable the saving of submissions…

- Goto /admin/structure/webform/manage/WEBFORM_ID/settings
- Check 'Disable saving of submissions'

[image]

Comment: The concern is that there can't be ANY storage of data in the 'primary' database submitted by end users.   So the "clicking of the submit button" would have either send that data to the other DB directly, or stop writing data to the primary DB and trigger that web service.

Comment: @alphex I updated the above answer to include notes on how to disable the saving of submissions.

Comment: Thank you @jrockowitz !   I obviously haven't looked at the settings screen in a while.